# What is the equivalent of DbGeography in EF core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, spatial

What is the equivalent of DbGeography in EF core?

I want to convert the following code from EF to EF Core:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

namespace Domain
{
    public class City
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        
        public DbGeography Coordinates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `NetTopologySuite` with EF Core and there is list of libraries which enables that for specific Data Provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial

Answer (score 4):

In order to use spatial data with EF Core, we need to install the appropriate supporting NuGet package.

For example Spatial NuGet Package of **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer** is **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite**

Then we can use this spatial types:

- Geometry
- Point
- LineString
- Polygon
- GeometryCollection
- MultiPoint
- MultiLineString
- MultiPolygon

By default, spatial properties are mapped to geography columns in SQL Server.

To use geometry, we configure the column type in our model.